# Neo4j Cypher Regular expression not matching

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to perform matching this property in my edge

> TargetObject: hklm\\software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\run\\xyz

why will this regular expression fail

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) where r.TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\software\\\\microsoft\\\\windows\\\\currentversion\\\\run.*' return n, r, m
```

Only the following can work

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) where r.TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\.*' return n, r, m
```

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: What you mean fail? This query return true: `WITH "hklm\\software\\microsoft\\windows\\currentversion\\run\\xyz" AS TargetObject
RETURN TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\software\\\\microsoft\\\\windows\\\\currentversion\\\\run.*'`

Comment: sorry what i meant was the first query did not return any result

Comment: I think that you need to provide an example of the data on which you can check the query. For example, in the console: http://console.neo4j.org/

Comment: You accidentally put a space before hklm didn't you? =P If `LTRIM(r.TargetObject)=~'<regex>'` fixes it, that is definitely your problem. (That's Left-Trim. There is also a RTRIM and TRIM function)

Comment: No there is no space before hklm. Even `'hklm\\\\.*'` also works. however the moment i add 's' to the regex `'hklm\\\\s.*'` it will not return me any results.

Comment: Revisiting this problem again. For the above string i want to capture,  what is the reason that this regular expression `r.TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\.*' ` works,  while this `r.TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\s.*'` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see if I can bring some clarity to this.

The regex `hklm\\\\s.*` is in a string object, which will escape the `\` when created and thus be saved as `hklm\\s.*`. Then once the regex is evaluated it is handled as a new string/regex object that also escapes the `\`. This means that the regex you search on is `hklm\s.*`, which doesn't match the target string (which has double `\`'s).

The regex `hklm\\\\.*` will then be `hklm\.*` which matches the target (since `.` matches any character), in difference to `hklm\s.*`.

To get the correct regex in the end you'll need more `\`'s (double the amount) in the original query regex. The regex `hklm\\\\\\\\s.*` will become `hklm\\s.*` when evaluated, which should match your target.

I tried this with a small example using Neo4j browser and adding the extra `\`'s does work then.

Hope this helps,
Therese
Neo4j employee

Answer (score 0):

the only workaround is to use this expression `r.TargetObject=~'hklm\\\\.*s.*'`